# phploc installation not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, pear, phploc

I am trying to install phploc on my ubuntu 13.04 and it doesn't seem to work here are the steps I followed.

```
$ sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
$ sudo pear install phpunit/phploc
phpunit/phploc can optionally use PHP extension "bytekit"
downloading phploc-1.7.4.tgz ...
Starting to download phploc-1.7.4.tgz (10,134 bytes) .....
done: 10,134 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/phploc-1.7.4 .de/phploc
```

Then when i type phploc it givies this error

> $ phploc
>  PHP Warning: 
>   require_once(SebastianBergmann/FinderFacade/autoload.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/autoload.php on line 44 PHP
>   Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phploc:0 PHP   2. require()
>   /usr/bin/phploc:48 PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening
>   required 'SebastianBergmann/FinderFacade/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php.;/usr/bin/pear.:/usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/')
>   in /usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/autoload.php on line 44 PHP
>   Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phploc:0 PHP   2. require()
>   /usr/bin/phploc:48

Here is my php include path

```
$ php -i | grep include <br>
allow_url_include => Off => Off
include_path => .:/usr/share/php.:/usr/bin/pear.:/usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/ => .:/usr/share/php.:/usr/bin/pear.:/usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPLOC/
MYSQL_INCLUDE => -I/usr/include/mysql
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the installation guide at:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the phploc archive from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc, moved it to /usr/bin/phploc.phar.

Then i created an alias in my .bashrc as below
alias phploc='/usr/bin/phploc.phar'

now i am able to access phploc like this

root@# phploc
phploc 1.7.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Usage: phploc [switches]  ...

--count-tests            Count PHPUnit test case classes and test methods.

--log-xml          Write result in XML format to file.
  --log-csv          Write result in CSV format to file.

--exclude           Exclude  from code analysis.
  --names           A comma-separated list of file names to check.
                           (default: *.php)

--help                   Prints this usage information.
  --version                Prints the version and exits.

--progress               Print progress bar.